# Concatenate last 100 files in an only one

Tags: python

Begginer in Python needs a bit of help. I am using Python 2.7.

I want to make a program that concatenates the last 100 files I have in a folder. In that folder I have lots of files but I only want the concatenation of the last 100 ones. I am able to do the concatenation of all of them (if I don´t specify number and change the for loop), but I am not able to select the last 100 files. These files are saved in binary by the software.They are saved in the folder specified below. I would like to remove that 100 files once are concatenated in teh new one.The program I have done is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
os.chdir("C:\AFM_test\jpk_files")
rout=""
filename=glob.glob("*-*-*.*.*-*.*.*.jpk-force")
filename.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
for filename in range(0,99):
    filename=open(filename,"rb")
    tout=filename.read()+\r\n"
    rout = rout+tout
    os.remove(filename)
    filename.close()
fout = open("output.jpk-force","wb+")
fout.write(rout)
fout.close()
```

It doesn´t do anything and the error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\AFM_test\jpk_files\AFM_test.py", line 12, in <module>
filename = open(filename,"rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I guess the problem is the loop and its structure "range(0,99)",as when I have concatenated all the files contained in the folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
os.chdir("C:\AFM_test\jpk_files")
rout=""
filename=glob.glob("*-*-*.*.*-*.*.*.jpk-force")
for filename in files:
    filename=open(filename,"rb")
    tout=filename.read()+\r\n"
    rout = rout+tout
    os.remove(filename)
    filename.close()
fout = open("output.jpk-force","wb+")
fout.write(rout)
fout.close()
```

it worked okay except the remove order, which showed this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\try\AFM_test_2.py", line 17, in <module>
os.remove(filename)
must be string, not file
```

Any ideas how can I achieve my goal?

I hope I have explained myself properly. Maybe I have missed something important, sorry, I am just a beginner in this field.

Thank you.

Comment: check all the variables on the line where the error is occurring. print them out and you'll see that issue.

Comment: You are assigning three different values of completely different kinds to `filename`, overwriting any previous value. First it's a glob list, then it's an integer, then it's an open file handle. Use different variables for different things for a start.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

That is because `filename` is an integer and then you are trying to concatenate it with a string.

---

> os.remove(filename)
>   must be string, not file

That is because you are re-assigning the variable filename (which was a string path) to a file handle/object. `os.remove(..)` expects the variable from the for-loop, not the result of `open(..)`. Its generally a good practice to give meaningful names to variables – `filepath` and `infile` etc.

---

A better approach would be:

```
def processFile(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        content = f.read()
        os.remove(filepath)
    return content

def main():
    paths = glob.glob("..*..*..")
    last100paths = paths[-100:]
    with open(outFilePath, "w") as f:
        f.write("\r\n".join(processFile(path) for path in last100paths))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
filename=open(filename,"rb")
```

...to something like:

```
inf = open(filename, "rb")
...

inf.close()
```

Then, when you're calling `os.remove(filename)`, it will *still* be the filename from the original loop, not a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) that your code is reassigning to this variable.

Note: rather than doing this explicit opening and closing of files, though, try using the `with` statement (see [this helpful guide](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)).

Answer (score -1):

Checn if `glob` is matching patterns

```
pattern = r"*-*-*.*.*-*.*.*.jpk-force"
filenames=glob.glob(pattern)
if not filenames:
    print 'no files matched ', pattern
    sys.exit(1)
```

Get mtime sorted file list by building list of tuples each containing file name and mtime

```
filenames = [ (filename,os.stat(filename)[8]) for filename in filenames ]
```

sort the list with mtime in descending order

```
filenames.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

The above two lines can be simplified as;

```
filenames = [ filename for filename in sorted(filenames,key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True) ]
```

The above line can be refactored, because we can sort in place
`filenames.sort(key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True)`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
os.chdir("C:\AFM_test\jpk_files")
rout=""  
pattern = r"*-*-*.*.*-*.*.*.jpk-force"
filenames=glob.glob(pattern)
if not filenames:
    print 'no files matched ', pattern
    sys.exit(1)

filenames.sort(key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True)
for filename in filenames[:100]
    filecontent=open(filename,"rb")
    tout=filecontent.read()+"\r\n"
    filecontent.close()
    rout = rout+tout
    os.remove(filename)

fout = open("output.jpk-force","wb+")
fout.write(rout)
fout.close()
```

You didn't check for exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was really close as I see. I have taken the model of Nizam Mohamed. But I have had a look at the other answers and I feel really grateful for it. I have learned a lot, thank you very much, seriously.

Comment: But in the for line, it would be:

Comment: for filename in filenames[-100:]:

Comment: I have reverse sorted the list. So get first 100 file names